# Quadratic Gauss sums and Fourier Analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis, abelian-groups, gauss-sums, poisson-summation-formula

Lately I have been reading this very interesting book [Mathematics++: Selected Topics Beyond the Basic Courses](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/stml/075) by Kantor, Matoušek and Šámal, especially Chapter 3 on Fourier analysis.

In *Section 5: Poisson Summation Formula* they pose the following questions in *Exercise 5.6*.

Let p be a prime and define the *Gauss sum* by
$$
\operatorname{Gau}(r) = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}_p} e(rx^2/p) \quad \text{where} \quad e(x) := \exp(2 \pi i x)
$$

1. Prove that $\operatorname{Gau}(rs^2) = \operatorname{Gau}(r)$ for $s \in \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \{0\}$. (**This one I have already proven since it is not that hard**)
2. Verify that if $-1$ is not a quadratic residue in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ then $\operatorname{Gau}(-r) = -\operatorname{Gau}(r)$.
3. Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_p^2$ and define $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ by putting $f(x_1, x_2) = e(r(x_1^2 + x_2^2)/p)$. Finally, let $H = \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \{0\}$ be a subgroup of $G$. Apply the Poisson summation formula (defined below) to prove that $\operatorname{Gau}(1)^2 = \pm p$. (The sign depends on whether -1 is a quadratic residue.)

**Poisson summation formula.**
Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Consider $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ and $x \in G$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{y \in H} f(x+y) = \sum_{a \in H^{\perp}} \widehat{f}(a) \chi_a(x),
$$
where $\chi_a(x) := e(\sum_{i = 1}^{k}\frac{a_i x_i}{n_i})$ for $G \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^k \mathbb{Z}_{n_i}$.

It seems to me that this is already given in the clearest manner possible, still, I am not able to deduce the 2nd and 3rd result. I have proven that $(\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus\{0\})^{\perp} = \{0\} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Maybe someone can take it from there.

Comment: Hint for $2$ : if $z$ is not a quadratic residue in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (in your case, $z=-1$), then show $Gau(r)+Gau(zr)=\sum_{y \in \mathbb{Z}_p} e(ry/p)$. This last sum can be computed directly, it's a geometric sum

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I guess it should be twice the sum you stated. I am currently revisiting the question and want to formulate a complete and correct answer to the problem.